# Using Javascript .length with dot notation and bracket notation produce different result

Tags: javascript, notation

I have read about the difference between both:
[Difference between dot and bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

However when I try to put together a simple HTML example using default JavaScript .length to refer to them:

```
<ul id="allList">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
</ul>

console.log(document.getElementById("allList").getElementsByTagName("li").length);
//6


console.log(document.getElementById("allList").getElementsByTagName("li")[length]); 
//<li>a</li>
```

Using **dot notation** is giving me **6** because it registers total of 6 arrays from the HTML but when comes to **bracket**, why is it giving me the **first html list** instead?

Working example here:
[sample code](http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/XKZoOw)

**Updates:**
Ok I just found out that I have missed out the quotes. It should be ["length"] instead of [length]. Question solved.

Comment: Do you have any variable with the name `length` defined in that scope?

Comment: I guess you should use `['length']` instead of `[length]`

Comment: Yes that, I have missed out the quotes.

Comment: @thefourtheye — Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length

Comment: "I just found out that I have missed out the quotes" — Three answers said that already. Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Quention I have read it before, as soon as I finish posting and some heads up from others I immediately saw that is a another silly mistake from my end. I know it is too late to delete the question now and people will start downvoting regardless whether is a silly mistake or not. I'm just trying my best not to get anymore downvotes....At the end of the day who doesn't make careless mistake.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square bracket notation takes a **string**. `length` is a variable. Since you haven't explicitly set it, [it is `window.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length) which is the number of frames in the document (which must be 0 since you are getting the first element in the node list).

If you want to access the length property then say `["length"]` and actually pass a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting 'length' in the brackets instead of length

Basically you try to access an object property. Here the object is an array but it works for other objects. You can access the property using ".propertyName" or using brackets with ['popertyName']

Comment: "object is an array" — No, it is an HTMLCollection

Comment: Yes you're right but it's easier to see it as an array to understand the length property ^^ But yes you're right ;)

Answer (score -1):

`[]` this means fetching element from an array. Seems like your 'length' variable is defined somewhere with 0 value, that's why it gives you first elem of 'li' array.

Comment: "element from an array" — Property from any kind of object. In this case, it is an  HTMLCollection, not an array.